# YT-DLP Return Format (m3u8)

Tags: javascript, hls.js, yt-dlp

I have a website that runs on node.js and express on the back end that in turn calls `.py` script to download a user-requested audio using [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp). When I run the website on the localhost, everything runs perfectly, and I get a .mp4 downloadable url that can be fed right into the JavaScript audio.

However, when I deploy my website on Heroku, the same `.py` script gives me a .m3u8 url which is an audio playlist, and it requires extra steps such as `hls` to be played with JavaScript.

**My question is why this happens.**

My Heroku buildpack contains `nodejs` and `python`. Am I missing `FFmpegExtractAudio` here or some yt-dlp formatting options below?

My `.py` script is

```
ydl_opts = {
'format': 'bestaudio/best',
'quiet': True,
'postprocessors': [{
    'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
    'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
    'preferredquality': '192',
}],}

with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
try:
    info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" %
                            requestedAudio, download=False)['entries'][0]
    # code follows...
except yt_dlp.utils.DownloadError or yt_dlp.utils.ExtractorError:
    # code follows...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: For those that have similar issue, I was able to fix the problem by changing the `yt-dlp` options. Specifically, I added `format` and `extractor_args` flags. Note: the above code worked on localhost, the below code worked on Heroku deployed webapp as well as the localhost. Happy coding!

```
ydl_opts = {
'format': '(bestaudio/best)[protocol~="^https?$"]',
'quiet': True,
'noplaylist': True,
'postprocessors': [{
    'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
    'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
    'preferredquality': '192',
}],
'extractor_args': {'youtube':{'player_client': ['android', 'web']}},
```